# OpenMP False Sharing

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp, false-sharing

I believe I am experiencing false sharing using OpenMP. Is there any way to identify it and fix it?

My code is: https://github.com/wchan/libNN/blob/master/ResilientBackpropagation.hpp line 36.

Using a 4 core CPU compared to the single threaded 1 core version yielded only 10% in additional performance. When using a NUMA 32 physical (64 virtual) CPU system, the CPU utilization is stuck at around 1.5 cores, I think this is a direct symptom of false sharing and unable to scale.

I also tried running it with Intel VTune profiler, it stated most of the time is spent on the "f()" and "+=" functions. I believe this is reasonable and doesn't really explain why I am getting such poor scaling...

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: False sharing doesn't decrease your CPU utilization. It just causes tons of cache misses.

Comment: @Mystical - My understanding was that on NUMA it might if the scheduler was scheduling all threads on the processors which owned the page to avoid migrating it around excessively.

Comment: @awoodland That's certainly a possibility - albeit another consequence of having everything adjacent in memory. (I didn't get your ping since you left out the second `i` in my UN.)

Answer (score 2):

Use reduction instead of explicitly indexing an array based on the thread ID.  That array virtually guarantees false sharing.

i.e. replace this

> ```
> #pragma omp parallel for 
>     clones[omp_get_thread_num()]->mse() += norm_2(dedy);
>
> for (int i = 0; i < omp_get_max_threads(); i++) {
>      neural_network->mse() += clones[i]->mse();
> ```

with this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : mse)
     mse += norm_2(dedy);

neural_network->mse() = mse;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of knowing for sure is looking at cache statistics with a tool like cachegrind :

```
valgrind --tool=cachegrind [command]
```

Comment: yes this is what i was thinking use thread profiling tools +1

Comment: It does support multiple threads, but valgrind uses it's own internal scheduler so the thread execution is sequentialized. I don't think cachegrind is a good choice here.